# Is there a sequence $a_k$ satisfying $e^{\lambda-\lambda^2}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}a_k$ for all $\lambda \in \Bbb R$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Is there a sequence of real numbers $a_k$ satisfying $e^{\lambda-\lambda^2}=\sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}a_k$ for all $\lambda \in \Bbb R$?

This is interesting because it is equivalent to asking whether there is an unbiased estimator $T(X)$ for $e^{-\lambda ^2}$ where $X \sim \operatorname{Poi}(\lambda)$. Indeed, if $e^{-\lambda^2}= \Bbb E[T] = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\lambda^k e^{-\lambda}}{k!}f(k) $ then we are left we finding the sequence $a_k = f(k)$. Thus $a_k \to \infty$. I know that there is an unbiased estimator for $e^tx$ for every $t \in \Bbb R$, and so this is a natural question.

Plugging in $\lambda =0,1$ we get that $a_0=1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k!}=1$. What other tricks might help?

Comment: These coefficients are all integers and appear as [A000321](http://oeis.org/A000321) at OEIS.org. (Actually, that's for $e^{-\lambda-\lambda^2}$. But this just flips the sign of every even term.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there is; this is just the Maclaurin series for $f(z)=\exp(z-z^2)$.
This is an entire function and the series converges everywhere on the complex plane. We can be reasonably explicit.

$$\exp(z-z^2)=e^ze^{-z^2}=\sum_{j,k=0}^\infty\frac{z^j}{j!}\frac{(-z^2)^{k}}{k!}$$
so
$$a_n=n!\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^k}{(n-2k)!k!}.$$
I'm not sure if one can simplify this further.

Comment: More explicitly, $a_n = H_n(1/2)$ where $H_n$ is the $n$-th Hermite polynomial.

Comment: Expanding on @RobertIsrael's remark, the Hermite polynomials have the EGF $e^{2xt-t^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x)(t^n/n!).$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact you can just take derivatives to compute them explicitly.  You'll get $$a_k = \frac{d^k}{d \lambda^k} e^{\lambda - \lambda^2} \bigg|_{\lambda = 0}$$